# How to sort dates from a list using Python

Tags: python

This list is organized by `day.month.year`. Before my list was a prefix. For example:
`[Objname].01.02.2020.log`. I used a regex `(\[Obj.*]).(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4})` for splitting the ObjectName from date. This is the resulted:

```
01.02.2020
02.02.2020
03.02.2020
04.02.2020
05.02.2020
06.02.2020
07.02.2020
08.02.2020
09.02.2020
10.02.2020
11.02.2020
12.02.2020
13.02.2020
14.02.2020
15.02.2020
16.02.2020
17.02.2020
18.02.2020
19.02.2020
20.02.2020
21.02.2020
22.02.2020
23.02.2020
24.02.2020
25.02.2020
26.02.2020
27.02.2020
29.01.2020
30.01.2020
31.01.2020
```

I used `sorted()` because the Objectname is composite by numbers and I needed return this files sorted. But I don't know how is the best way to handle with this.

```
def getFiles(numbers):
 currentDay = datetime.datetime.now()
 numdays  = numbers
 dateList = []
 for x in range (0, numdays):
  date = currentDay - datetime.timedelta(days = x)
  days = date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
  dateList.append(days)

 path = "/var/log/"

 files = sorted([filename for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path)
          for filename in files
          for date in dateList
          if filename.endswith(date+".log")])

 return files
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your dates are in `dd.mm.yyyy` order, and you want to sort them in `yyyy.mm.dd` order; so you can use a `key` function which splits on `.` and reverses the components.

```py
>>> date_strings = ['01.01.2009', '04.07.2007', '05.06.2007', '06.06.2007']
>>> sorted(date_strings, key=lambda d: d.split('.')[::-1])
['05.06.2007', '06.06.2007', '04.07.2007', '01.01.2009']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you reorder it so that the year is first, then the month, then the day, string-based sorting should work as expected.